# How do I use Python Regex to find a sentence with a capitalized word at the end?

Tags: python, regex, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on an assignment for class (in jupyter) where I need to write a `regex` statement in Python that will return all lines (the document is already split apart) with a word completely capitalized at the end.

For example, if I have the following sentences:

I like APPLES.

I like oranges.

I like POTATOES.

The first and third sentence should come back to me. Here's what I've tried:

```
my_regex = r".*[^a-z][A-Z]$"
[line for line in poemlines if re.search(my_regex, line)]
```

and

```
my_regex = r"\b[^a-z][A-Z]{0,10}$"
[line for line in poemlines if re.search(my_regex, line)]
```

Comment: @Abrar "doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem. Plus, it seems to be matching just fine in the link in my comment.

Comment: @41686d6564 Lol..Sorry about that. It literally printed nothing, when I ran it.

Comment: You could use `^.*\b[A-Z]+\.?$` https://regex101.com/r/vG8azN/1

Answer (score 0):

You tried:

```
r".*[^a-z][A-Z]$"
```

This matches anything `.*`, followed by a character that's not a single lowercase letter `[^a-z]`, followed by a character that's a single uppercase letter `[A-Z]` and then the end of the string `$`.

And you tried:

```
r"\b[^a-z][A-Z]{0,10}$"
```

This matches a word boundary `\b`, followed by a character that's not a single lowercase letter `[^a-z]`, followed by 0-10 uppercase letters `[A-Z]{0,10}` and then the end of the string `$`.

I find that often programmers new to regexes are confused by them and end up just trying a bunch of stuff - it really helps to understand the meaning of every character in your regex and online regex tools can help with that, as they tend of offer a full explanation (like regex101.com)

Something like this makes sense:

```
import re

poemlines = ['I like APPLES.', 'I like oranges.', 'I like POTATOES.']

my_regex = r'\b[A-Z]+\.$'
print([line for line in poemlines if re.search(my_regex, line, re.MULTILINE)])
```

This works because it matches a word boundary `\b`, followed by an uppercase letter one or more times `[A-Z]+`, followed by a literal period `\.` and then the end of the string `$`.

See the explanation here https://regex101.com/r/XstTcc/1 and play around with it. Note that it also works without the `, re.MULTILINE`, but this is because each line is its own string. In a situation where you'd be matching in a text with multiple lines, you'd want that there.